# I cannot move REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR using Exchange Web Services API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Web Services API to move messages from an Inbox to a public folder. The operation works when the Inbox item is an IPM.Note but the undeliverable messages, REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR, fail with "The move or copy operation failed."

Do I need to do something special to get the REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR items to move?

The logic is simple, Bind and then Move:
tMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, myMessage.Id, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
tMessage.Move({public folder}.Id)

*** Update ***
I have found that NDM messages for external addresses come in from "Mail Delivery System" and those messages can be moved. NDM Messages when internal addresses are invalid come from "Microsoft Outlook" and those messages cannot be moved. They are both REPORT.IPM.Note.NDM so I don't know what the differences are or how to distinguish between processing between the two.

Comment: It really sounds like a bug to me, they are just both store items so there should be no difference when you moving them. Have you tried a copy and delete instead ? this is what Move is doing anyway and that might narrow it down as to what is failing

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types of "Mail Delivery Notifications" when using MS Exchange. The first one is created without really leaving the Exchange ecosystem. For example you send an email to a Exchange user and while you send that out the user got a bigger email and is then over quota. Then you got a error message back directly from your Exchange server. The other email is generated my the Exchange transport system, for example you send an email to another company and it would leave the Exchange ecosystem. Then a remote email environment would generate such a "Mail Delivery Notifications" and for example would inform you that person XY in the remote company is over quota.

Without checking the difference here and without knowing which Server you are using (2010, 2013, 2017, Exchange Online, ...) its not easy to answer what might be the difference here. However out of the blue the first "Mail Delivery Notifications" might be pure MAPI and the 2nd one might be Plaintext/HTML. You can check that on your own when you validate the email header / source. Then we can say that for sure.

Comment: I did find out that the NDM that I cannot move came from Exchange, it was because of an internal email address that was bad. NDMs from external are moving fine. It is just the internal notifications that I cannot move. It looks like I am accessing Exchange 2010_SP3.

Comment: Another piece of information: OWA (Outlook Web App) can't move that NDM either. But the Outlook Desktop Client can move it. If NDM is from MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@{internal domain}.com then it won't move. If it is from MAILER-DAEMON@{exchange server} then it will move.

Comment: OWA gave a generic error that it couldn't be moved, just like the EWS API did. Only the Outlook Desktop Application is able to move it.